# C# Value Cannot be null using Path.Combine

Tags: c#, .net, directory, path

I'm attempting to construct a database using the C# Console, but I'm getting an error thrown that I can't seem to find the problem with. The problem is in my Query function, when I attempt to define the path based off of user input. Essentially, it looks into a given folder in the user folder, and within it another subfolder containing the files wherein is the database information. Im using the Path.Combine function to dynamically define the path throughout my code, but I'm getting the following error;

ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path3')

Even though all strings are defined and not null.

this is what the line of code looks like:

```
path = Path.Combine(Info.path, "infolder", classrooms.inventory, classrooms.geninv, userinput)
```

And here is all of the code that the strings in the path arguement are referencing:

```
class classrooms
{
    public static string Teacher;
    public static string Roomnumber;
    public static string Changes;
    public static string inventory = "inventory";
    public static string geninv = "GenInv";
    public static string classinv = "ClassInv";
}
```

and

```
class Info
    {
        public static string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
    }
```

if necessary I can attach my full code.

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ot36.png)

Comment: I'd guess `userinput` is `null`

Comment: @ThomasSchremser No, because userinput is defined by a readline function in the line of code directly preceding the pathcombine function.     string userinput = Console.ReadLine();

Comment: The error states that the `path3` parameter is `null`. Make sure that `classrooms.inventory` (in the position of `path3`) is not null when you call `Path.Combine`.

Comment: @MattU It isn't null, which is the problem here. I defined it in the classrooms class with public static string inventory = "inventory";

Comment: Error is not in Path.Combine. It's your `perhaps.Functions` type constructor that's throwing exception.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
It was an improperly defined string that the pathcombine function was using in another instance of the code, and it was just getting caught up once i reused the path.combine function. Thanks for all the answers, I wouldn't have thought to look at that without all the input.

Comment: That being that the Roomnumber string wasn't defined in the classrooms class. It had to be assigned to a string apparently.